# Alert when file content changes

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script which checks all the logic files placed at `/var/www/html/` and, if a user makes any change in those files, sends an alert to an administrator informing them that "User x has made change in f file." I do not have much experience in writing shell scripts, and for this I do not know how to start. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: look at dnotify ... its an interface for scripting notifications on changes to files or directories.

Comment: logic files keyword is used for all web-files or any php-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Basically you use [`inotifywait`](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/)

> > Simple, using inotifywait:

```
while inotifywait -e close_write myfile.py; do ./myfile.py; done
```

> > This has a big limitation: if some program replaces myfile.py with a different file, rather than writing to the existing myfile, inotifywait will die. Most editors work that way.
> >
> > To overcome this limitation, use inotifywait on the directory:

```
while true; do
  change=$(inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create .)
  change=${change#./ * }
  if [ "$change" = "myfile.py" ]; then ./myfile.py; fi
done
```

The asker has even put a [script online](http://bitbucket.org/denilsonsa/small_scripts/src) for that, which can be called like this:

```
while sleep_until_modified.sh derivation.tex ; do latexmk -pdf derivation.tex ; done
```

Comment: hi actually i got a way out but still there is one issue-:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
while true
do
   ATIME=`stat -c %Z /path/to/the/file.txt`
   if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]
   then
       echo "RUN COMMNAD"
       LTIME=$ATIME
   fi
   sleep 5
done......but how to know if there is any change made in crontab -e and i still dont know how to catch one who had made changes..

Comment: Did you try to use this script?
https://bitbucket.org/denilsonsa/small_scripts/src/96af96e23bc1e19c9156412cdbb8eeba09e21cad/sleep_until_modified.sh?at=default

And sorry, I don't think you can find out the person who made the change, because that information is not saved anywhere in the file content.

Comment: yes i did but it works ....i am still searching to know how the particular user can be caught.... i will request you to share if you find any thing on this....thanks ,,,,...i too share

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you should probably take a look at the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html). It's about Bash specifically, but you may find it helpful even if you're not using Bash. As far as watching for changes in files, try [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). There are also [tools available](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) to make it usable directly from the command line, which have worked quite nicely in my experience.

Now, there are a few other ways you might approach this problem. You might look at [md5deep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) and [ssdeep](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/). They are tools designed for digital forensics which can create a list of [cryptographic hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash) (in the case of md5deep) or fuzzy hashes (in ssdeep's case) and later scan against that list and tell you which files have appeared, disappeared, changed, moved, etc. Or, if you want to detect potentially unauthorized changes, you might look at a [host-based intrusion detection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host-based_intrusion_detection_system) such as [OSSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSSEC). Apparently, these can both scan for file changes and watch for other signs of unauthorized activity.